# PHP constantly serves the same data

Tags: php, python-3.x, apache2

I have implemented a website click counter. Whenever I access my website, it will not change what it is serving (and the number stays the same). The expected behavior was that it would increment the number of clicks, but it did not.

I thought that the page was served was being cached on the browser, so I looked at some results on Stack Overflow. Some SO answers suggested to put `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` for modern browsers. That seemed to make the page fully reload but the number did not change. The result was still the same. Then I tried it on another device and it showed the same number (the counter did not go up). I tried again with caching completely disabled. Still nothing!

Then I thought that the page may be cached on the server instead. I looked some results on SO again and someone suggested `clearstatcache();` but that did nothing to help.

Further investigation relieved that running `php index.php` within the directory worked as intended. The counter incremented and page contents were spat out into the console. I refreshed the page on my browser (no cache) and the number increased to the one that was spat out into my console. But it did not increase when refreshed consecutively.

My PHP code: (`index.php`)

```
<?php
clearstatcache(); //tried this but it doesn't help
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //Also doesn't help
$hits = exec("python3 hitsAdd.py"); //Execute a Python Script. 
?>

<!-- [unimportant html] -->

<?php echo "$hits";?>
```

My Python 3 code: (`hitsAdd.py`)

```py
try:
    f = open("hits.txt")
    hits = int(f.read())
    f.close()
except:
    hits = 0

print(hits)

hits += 1
f = open("hits.txt", "w")
f.write(str(hits))
f.close()
```

`hits.txt` is a file that contains just a number. For example:

```
10
```

Comment: Do you really need PHP and Apache? Why not just use all Python with Flask?

Comment: I could do it in pure PHP. Same result. I don't want to use Falsk

Comment: Okay, fine. Is the file actually changing on just the first request?